# Appendix comes empty in ACM LaTeX template

Tags: appendices, acmart

I am using `acmart.cls` ACM [template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) to author a paper.I have three appendix sections. Surprisingly, as and when I keep writing, the appendix sections in the generated PDF file sometimes appears, sometimes disappears. Even if they appear, most of the times the formatting is malformed. I cannot reproduce the issue in a small scale, therefore I cannot provide an MWE. Sorry for that. The log has no mention of any related issue. Does someone have any ideas?

Comment: Please post a MWE.

Comment: you can always produce a MWE. Simply remove everything that is not relevant and then post the rest.